# Use AngularJS directive to change classes of ng-repeat elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to conditionally change the class of an element that is nested in an unordered list.

When not using `ng-repeat` to create the list, I can use the jqlite selector `.children()` to find the correct element and change the class.

However I am using `ng-repeat` to create the list and I can't figure out how to access the specific list element that I want. `.children()` always returns undefined.

here is a jsfiddle of what I am trying to do
http://jsfiddle.net/whitehead1415/ENtTC/3/

```
app.directive('myDirective1', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            //for some reason element.children()[0] is undefined
            //why? what can I do about it?
            angular.element(element.children()[0]).css('background', 'grey')
        }
    };
});
```

I need to be able to change the class based on 2 things

1. when the user clicks on the specific element the element needs to highlight
2. when the user clicks on a button that is the next element will be highlighted (that button isn't included in the jsfiddle)

I thought about putting the directive on each list element, but the only problem is that I don't know how to make them all aware of each other so only one element is highlighted at a time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `ng-repeat` alters the template DOM in such a way that the children do not exist at the time the directive compiles.  You need to set a `$watch` on `element.children()` in the directive so that the directive will be notified when the children are added and apply the CSS at that time.  Do this in your `link` function (which is a `postLink` function when declared as a directive method):

```
$scope.$watch(element.children(),function(){
    var children = element.children();
    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        if(children[i].nodeType !== 8){
            angular.element(children[i]).css('background', 'grey');
        }
    }
});
```

The `$watch` also needs to check and make sure that the `nodeType` is not a comment (type `8`) because `ng-repeat` inserts comments, which will throw an error if you try to apply CSS.

**Fiddle**: Here is the <kbd>[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/gdfTP/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks this works! someone on the angular mailing list told me the same thing.