# Angularjs: custom grid component, dynamically add <br> elements

Tags: angularjs, grid, angularjs-directive, custom-component, dom-manipulation

Ok, I have made a really simple grid component. I fetch a column count attribute and add a `<br>` tag after the end of a row. I do that within the link function.

Her is the directive: http://pastebin.com/U4ckuKJw

grid.html just looks like this: `<div class="grid" data-ng-transclude=""></div>`

In my first example I have 7 `<div>` tags inside the grid component and want to have 3 columns. So after every third `<div>` I want a `<br>` to be added.

It looks like this and is working:
`<div data-grid="" data-cols="5">`

`<div>1</div>`

`<div>2</div>`

`<div>3</div>`

`<div>4</div>`

`<div>5</div>`

`<div>6</div>`

`<div>7</div>`

`</div>`

This one is not working: http://pastebin.com/wtcgM2Hv

I think it is because of the directive ng-repeat and that the content of the grid component isn't rendered at the time the link function ist executed.

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem or how to optimise the component?

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach may be to solve the problem with standard angular directives and css. For instance, if you float your cells and `clear: left` on those cells that start a new row, you can use `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` to accomplish this.

I created an example at: http://jsbin.com/idukaz/1

The html looks like this. Note I'm using `ng-class` to apply the class that formats the cell that needs to start a new row depending on the result of calling the custom `columnEnd` function. `columnBreak` is a scope variable for the number of columns you want. `$index` is a variable generated by `ng-repeat`:

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="label" 
         ng-class="{'new-row': startNewRow($index, columnBreak) }"
         ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }} ({{ $index + 1 }})</div>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```js
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    // list of grid data
    scope.items = [];

    // controls the number of columns
    scope.columnBreak = 5;

    // calculates if current cell is start of new row
    scope.startNewRow = function (index, count) {
        return ((index) % count) === 0;
    };
}]);
```

In your css if you float your cells and clear left, you'll get your columns to dynamically
reformat when you change the `columnBreak` value.

```css
.label {
    float: left;

}

.new-row {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: That's definetly a better approach. But I would like to hide the ng-class directive from the user. The directive sould be responsable for that. Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you gain by trying to hide the ng-class directive, but here's an example of the same thing wrapped in a custom directive: http://jsbin.com/ikobig/2 The only real difference is the row length is fed to the directive similar to what you have in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found the solution: 

[use angular directive to change classes of ng-repeat elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751487/use-angular-directive-to-change-classes-of-ng-repeat-elements)

I mixed it with Marks idea and manipulate the css classes now.

Thanks